# Unresponsive after screen lock; sleep restores responsiveness, but I lose my GUI session

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

I have been finding over the last few days that often (but not always), after I have pressed the screen lock button, my laptop will not wake, no matter which keys or buttons I press. This is a new problem, but I can't think of anything that has changed apart from normal Ubuntu software updates.

Closing the lid to trigger a sleep and then opening it again restores responsiveness to keyboard and touchpad input, but the price I pay is that I find myself in a new GUI session. All my apps from the previous session have closed, including the ones running long jobs that I don't want to be interrupted.

How can I fix this?

Additional information:

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

When the machine wakes from sleep, three lines of messages are briefly displayed before entering GUI mode about some problem with Bluetooth (I can make a note of them next time it happens if they are important). However, Bluetooth continues to work fine after waking from sleep.